# Обратный двоичный код

Tags: системы-счисления

Может кто-нибудь конструктивно изложить как был придуман обратный код, на каких идеях?
Почему при сложении числа в прямом коде и обратном мы получаем их разность, как так?
Где можно почитать об этом?

Answer (score -1):

Обратный код — метод вычислительной математики, позволяющий вычесть одно число из другого, используя только операцию сложения над натуральными числами.

Собственно это и есть идея.

Происходит это из-за особенностей математических операций над двоичными числами.

Читай - [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратный_код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Смотри - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiY0lKDgzi4

Comment: Ссылка на ответ вместо ответа. И вообще, больше похоже на отписку.